# 特定の箇所をクリックした場合のみ実行する意図の処理が、それ以外をクリックしても実行されてしまう

Tags: java

以下のプログラムで、インスタンスメソッド

```
public void hito(int x, int y) {
    double a= x+y ;
    System.out.println(a);
    
}
```

を定義し、外側クラスで

```
circles[3].hito(evt.getX(), evt.getY());
```

と書きました。これは、3つ目の円をクリックした際に、x座標の値と、y座標の値の合計を表示させようという意図です。
しかし、実際に実行してみると、パネル内のどこをクリックしても、座標値の合計が出てしまいます。つまり、3つ目の円以外の箇所どこでもクリックしても、表示されてしまい、circles[3]と指定した意味がなくなっています。
なぜこのようなことが起こるのでしょうか？

```
  import java.awt.*;
  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.awt.event.*;

  public class Sample91ex3 extends JPanel {
    Circle[] circles = new Circle[20];
    //Circle sel = null;

    public Sample91ex3() {
      setOpaque(false);
      int x = 30;
      for (int i = 0; i<20 ; ++ i) {
        circles[i] = new Circle(Color.black, x, 100, 15);
        x = x + 40;  
      }

      addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
          for (int i = 0; i<20 ; ++ i) {
            if(circles[i].hit(evt.getX(), evt.getY())) {
             // sel = circles[i];
              circles[i].changeColor();
              circles[i].moveBy(10, 10);
              
              repaint();
            }
            

          }
        circles[3].hito(evt.getX(), evt.getY());
        }
      });
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {circles[i].draw(g); }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame app = new JFrame();
      app.add(new Sample91ex3());
      app.setSize(800, 300);
      app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      app.setVisible(true);
    }


    static class Circle {
      int xpos, ypos, rad;
      Color col;
      public Circle(Color c, int x, int y, int r) {
        col = c ; xpos = x; ypos = y; rad = r;
      }
      public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(col);
        g.fillOval(xpos-rad, ypos-rad, rad*2, rad*2);
      }
      public void moveBy(int x, int y) {
        xpos = xpos + x ; ypos = ypos + y;
      }

      public void moveTo(int x, int y) {
        xpos = x; ypos = y;
      }
      public boolean hit(int x, int y) {
        return (xpos-x)*(xpos-x) + (ypos-y)*(ypos-y) <= rad*rad;
      }

      public void hito(int x, int y) {
        double a= x+y ;
        System.out.println(a);
        
      }
      public void setColor(Color c) {
        col = c;
      }
      public void changeColor() {
        col = new Color((int)(Math.random()*255),(int)(Math.random()*255),
                        (int)(Math.random()*255));
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 3つ目の円以外の箇所どこでもクリックしても、表示されてしまい、circles[3]と指定した意味がなくなっています。
> なぜこのようなことが起こるのでしょうか？

引数で渡しているのはクリックした座標ですが、その座標が円の中であるかを判定する必要があります。

```java
public void hito(int x, int y) {
    if (hit(x, y)) {
        double a = x + y;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

---

なお、

```java
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
            if (circles[i].hit(evt.getX(), evt.getY())) {
                // ...
                repaint();
            }

        }
        circles[3].hito(evt.getX(), evt.getY());
    }
});
```

の `circles[3].hito(evt.getX(), evt.getY());` についてですが、

- このタイミングでは既に円は移動済み。つまり判定することになるのは、「移動済みの円の中にクリックした座標が含まれるか」になります。それが意図した挙動でないのなら、forループの前に実行することになると思います。
- 配列の添字は`0`始まりなので、`circles[3]`というのは実際には4つめの円であることに注意してください。(質問文を見る限り、意図しているのは `circles[2]` ではないかという気もします)